# Is the inverse image of a group also a group for semigroup homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups, finite-semigroups

> If $\varphi : S \to T$ is a surjective semigroup homomorphism between semigroups and $G \subseteq T$ is a group, then is $\varphi^{-1}(G)$ also a group?

I know that this result holds if $S$ and $T$ are finite, as then I can find an idempotent element in $\varphi^{-1}(1_G)$ and everything follows from that. But I cannot prove it for infinite semigroups, nor can I find a counter-example.

Comment: *Hint*: Try the semigroup $S=\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @user10354138 I added the homomorphism to be surjective, to you still think that $S = \mathbb N$ will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Project $\Bbb{N}$ on $\{0,1\}=\Bbb{Z}/(2)$, sending evens to $0$ and odds to $1$.  So, no, the inverse image of a group under a semigroup homomorphism need not be a group, even if it is a surjective monoid homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement

> I know that this result holds if $S$ and $T$ are finite, as then I can
>   find an idempotent element in $\varphi^{-1}(1_G)$ and everything
>   follows from that.

is unfortunately wrong. Let $T$ be the trivial group $1$, let $S$ be any finite non-group semigroup and let $\varphi:S \to T$ be the trivial map. Then $\varphi^{-1}(1) = S$ and thus $\varphi^{-1}(1)$ is not a group.

The correct statement is

> Let $S$ be finite semigroup and let $\varphi : S \to T$ be a surjective semigroup morphism. Then for every group $G \subseteq T$, there exists a group $H \subseteq S$ such that $\varphi(H) = G$.